# Communicate with user about edit

Tags: support, edits, meta

Recently I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556331/how-to-get-roslyn-version-used-by-visual-studio-code-analysis) that a user [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20154295). The [reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5359302/george-alexandria) removed one of my tags, which I'm now assuming relates to my problem (he removed the Roslyn tag, and I'm starting to think that I'm actually NOT using roslyn).

I wish to contact to user, and inquire if this is the case, and if not so, what the reason is for removing the tag. I found another [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user), as well as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user), where IM is discussed, and why it's not there. Is there any other way I can ask my reviewer why he did this?

Comment: Do you know the user name of the reviewer?

Comment: "George Alexandria", https://stackoverflow.com/users/5359302/george-alexandria

Comment: Easier to edit your question and re-add the tag, if you think it is relevant.

Comment: I do not know anything about that stack, but it is interesting that you do not mention that tag's technology until the last word of the last line of your question. Maybe you should edit your question to make its relevance more prominent?

Comment: Did you try to add a @GeorgeAlexandria in a comment on your own question, asking for explanation? (Hi George, if you see this, "pinging" you as a side effect is half-intentional.)

Comment: Thanks @yivi , that is pretty much exactly what I wanted. Not sure how I missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If a post has been edited, you can @-comment the editor in a comment under the post.

The editor's name will not be shown automatically like that of posters or commenters, you have to type it in full. (Personally I use copy-paste the name, to make sure special characters get added in correctly.) But they will get a notification.

Note that this only holds for successful edits. Editors of Rejected edits don't get these notifications.

Alternatively, you can add a comment under one of their own posts, but that's less desirable because it's off-topic on their posts; it's about one of *your* posts.
And, of course, you can sometimes contact people in chatrooms, if the room's rules allow this use.